# Progress Bar not showing in screen but showing in debugger

Tags: android

I am adding a Progress Bar when the user does a search query, and it will not show up in the screen. Here are the snippets:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //main layout, which has a child layout called resultsLayout
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            EditText searchString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchString);
            search(searchString.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    protected void search(String searchString){
        LinearLayout resultLayout = ((LinearLayout)    findViewById(R.id.resultsLayout));
        resultLayout.addView(DisplayResults.getLoadBar(getApplicationContext()));
        //do search
        resultLayout.removeAllViews();
    }

    public static ProgressBar getLoadBar(Context context){
        ProgressBar loadBar = new ProgressBar(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        loadBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        loadBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return loadBar;
    }
```

I know some of it might not be needed, like the setVisibility right when creating, but I have tried several things and it not works. Perhaps there wasn't enough time to show up the bar?(It takes about 1.5sec for the search)

I have also debugged the application, and it shows the ProgressBar as a child of the layout, but I still cannot see it in the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog; //Create a prog dialog object
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this); //init it
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        progressDialog.show(); //show it when needed
        EditText searchString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchString);
        search(searchString.getText().toString());
    }
});

protected void search(String searchString){
    progressDialog.dismiss();//dismiss it when the search is complete
    LinearLayout resultLayout = ((LinearLayout)    findViewById(R.id.resultsLayout));
    resultLayout.addView(DisplayResults.getLoadBar(getApplicationContext()));
    //do search
    resultLayout.removeAllViews();
}
```

You could try this ProgressDialog object implementation. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Comment: It says the function is deprecated, and I still could not do what I originally wanted.

Comment: Says which function is deprecated ? Can you post a picture of it ?

Comment: That won't be a problem. You can still use it .

Answer (score 0):

add `setContentView(resultLayout);` at the end of `search()` method

Comment: That should not be it. I took out a couple of things from the onCreate, I will add it to make it clear.

Comment: add all of them pragmatically if you can

Answer (score 0):

I realized that android does not update the screen for every instruction in the code, apparently it does so only when a function ends. That being said, I had to do my search in a separate thread in order for the loading to appear between the time the searched started and before it ended.